# How to resolve 'Your session has expired' error when adding products to cart in Magento 2.4.2?

Tags: php, magento2

I am facing an issue in my Magento 2.4.2 installation. Every time I try to add products to the cart from the category page, I receive the error message "Your session has expired". However, I am able to add products to the cart without any issues from other parts of the store.
I have tried to resolve the issue by following these steps:

```
I updated the base URLs in the core_config_data table using the Magento CLI commands:
```

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://MYURL.com/"
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://MYURL.com/"`
```

I cleared the Magento cache using the command:

```
  php bin/magento cache:clean`
```

However, the issue persists and I am unable to add products to the cart from the product page.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue in Magento 2.4.2 and can provide any guidance or solution? Is there any other step I can take to resolve this problem?

I appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide. Thank you in advance!

I tried updating the base URLs in the core_config_data table of my Magento 2.4.2 installation and cleared the cache using Magento CLI commands.